# Node.JS not querying local DNS

Tags: node.js, dns, skydns

I have just installed locally SkyDNS and I am not resolve the IP address from a Node's dns lookup. My resolv.conf has only one entry:

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

result from dig:

```
$ dig service.skydns.local

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> service.skydns.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25842
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service.skydns.local.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
service.skydns.local.   3600    IN  A   10.0.1.125

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 16 10:41:21 BRT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

When I try to resolve using Node's dns lookup:

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.lookup('service.skydns.local', function(err, res, fam){console.log(err, res, fam);})

{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND service.skydns.local]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'service.skydns.local' } undefined undefined
```

Using resolve4 instead of lookup it works, but why won't lookup resolve this address from the local dns?

Comment: It depends, what does your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` have on the `hosts` line?

Comment: @mscdex: thank you for your answer. I have `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins`. It worked when I changed the priority of dns: `hosts: dns files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the priority of dns at /etc/nsswitch.conf it works:

```
hosts: dns files
```